# Confirmation of FTP upload for user

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ftp

I'm moving a task from manual to automatic

I'm well aware that you can't check for errors when doing this, but that's not my goal.

My code works as expected, but I'm missing... something

I need to let the user know that after I've put the file in the FTP location, that it was uploaded and they no longer need to wait for the file.

I've done this up to now by blagging the user, once the command has run, they just get told it's worked

```
@echo off

REM Generates the script
echo open 000.000.000.000> temp.txt
echo username>> temp.txt
echo password>> temp.txt
echo lcd "N:\line\line\line">> temp.txt
echo put file.txt>> temp.txt
echo quit>> temp.txt


REM Open FTP and run the script above
ftp -s:temp.txt


REM Remove the temp file
del temp.txt


REM Display confirmation
msg %username% "File sent to FTP"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I will add any more info if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to download the file back to see if it was correctly uploaded and do `fc`.

For unattened file download via `ftp` look at [robvanderwoude's ftp](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/ftp.php).  Don't forget that when saving the downloaded file it should have different name than the one you were uploading originally.

Then simply compare the files you have via `fc` command like this:

```
@echo off
fc c:\temp.txt r:\temp_to_check.txt > nul
if errorlevel 1 goto error

goto :EOF

:error
echo "The file was uploaded and downloaded incorrectly"
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you! I'll show the answer below

Answer (score 1):

Answer specific to my question for visual purposes:

```
REM Open FTP and run the script above
ftp -s:temp.txt


REM File check
fc "N:\line\line\TEST.TXT" "N:\line\line\check_location\TEST.TXT" > nul
if errorlevel 1 goto error


REM Remove the temp file
del temp.txt


REM Display confirmation
msg %username% "File has now been sent to FTP"

goto :EOF

:error
msg "The file was uploaded or downloaded incorrectly"
```